# Parent Reference in Query DB when Creating database in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following Classes

```
public class Children {
     public Children (){} // constructor
     public int Id {get;set;}, 
     public string ChildName {get; set;}
}
public class Parents {
     public Parents(){} // constructor
     public int Id {get;set;}, 
     public string ParentName {get;set;}
     public Children Child {get; set;}
}
```

I want 1 child per parent, In the configuration I have

```
  public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Parents> configuration)
  {  
       configuration.ToTable("Parents");
       configuration.Property(p => p.Id).HasField("_id");
       configuration.HasOne(a => a.ChildClass).WithMany().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
  }


  public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Children> configuration)
  {  
       configuration.ToTable("Children");
       configuration.Property(p => p.Id).HasField("_id");
  }
```

When I use the entity framework 5 builder I get 2 tables back from the database

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Parents](
     [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
     [ChildId] [int] NOT NULL,
     [ParentName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Parents] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)
WITH 
    (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Parents]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT 
    [FK_Parents_Children_Child] FOREIGN KEY([ChildId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Children] ([Id])
    ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Parents] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Parents_Parents_Children_ChildId]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Children](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ChildName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ParentId] [int] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Children] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
     [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
      ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Children]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Children_Parent_ParentId] FOREIGN 
     KEY([ParentId])
     REFERENCES [dbo].[Parents] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Children] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Children_Parent_ParentId]
GO
```

Basically I get stuck in a loop as I cannot insert a `Parents` record, and I cannot insert a son as they need both sets of Id's, I dont know why the `Children` table needs a reference to the `Parents` table, if the parents table already references the `Children` table.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your fluent mapping, it looks like you've set up a one-to-many relationship, where each child can have many parents. But you actually want a [one-to-one relationship](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#one-to-one).

```cs
public class Children {
    public Children (){}
    public int Id { get;set; }
    public string ChildName { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public Parents Parent { get; set; }
}
public class Parents {
     public Parents(){}
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string ParentName { get; set; }
     public Children Child { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Parents> configuration)
{  
    configuration.ToTable("Parents");
    configuration.Property(p => p.Id).HasField("_id");
    configuration.HasOne(p => p.Child).WithOne(c => c.Parent).HasForeignKey<Children>(c => c.ParentId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
}
```

However, the generated SQL doesn't seem to match your model nor your fluent configuration.